# Binary data conversion in Python

Tags: python, byte

I am pulling three 8 bit registers from a controller using Python. The three registers combined constitute a single 24 bit integer number - so first register/byte is bits 0-7 of the word, second register/byte is bits 8-15, third register/byte is bits 16-23. Mathematically what I think need to do is concatenate the three registers/bytes into a single 24 bit binary word, then convert binary to decimal. But - I need to strictly keep the byte format so if leading zeros in one of the byte words are removed - that's a problem. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: please provide an example input/desired output, your attempts at it and specify what python version you use. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: For example suppose input Reg 3 = 123 , (b'01111011), Reg 2 = 230, b'11100110' and Reg 1 = 15, b(00001111). The outputted 24bit word would be b'011110111110011000001111' =  8119823. I have tried "bin()" for example, but bin(15) just returns '(1111)' and I would need to pack 4 0's to retain the full 8 bit width. Using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ought to work for unsigned quantities:

```
>>> b1, b2, b3 = 0x80, 0x40, 0x20
>>> n = (b3 << 16) | (b2 << 8) | b1
>>> n
2113664
>>> format(n, ',d')
'2,113,664'
>>> hex(n)
'0x204080'
>>> bin(n)
'0b1000000100000010000000'
```

Comment: That concatenates the bytes, how would I convert that binary back to decimal?

Comment: `n` in my answer is a Python integer, which are always stored internally as binary data but, by default, the value of one will normally be displayed or printed in decimal. I thought that adding calls to the `hex()` and `bin()` functions to also display the result in those bases would make it clearer that the technique worked — obviously I was incorrect. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - sorry - I'm a little slow. Trying to translate my Fortran knowledge to a new language :-)